# get last day of week

Tags: mysql, database, date

i have field called day_id , and Apsent_Date .

the day_id contain integers (1,2,3,4,5) from Sunday until Thursday cuz sunday start from 1 .

and apsent date such as "2013-10-30" .

My question is : how to get Thursday date with using day_id = 5 .

i have tired something like :

```
SELECT apssent_date FROM apsent WHERE day_id = DAYOFWEEK( CURDATE( ) ) -3)
```

-3 means three days past from Sunday

lets suppose current day is Sunday which should return day_id = 1 .

Comment: Do you want to get the date of the last Thursday? `SELECT max(apsent_date) from apsent where day_id=5`

Comment: what is diffrence between your query and this :    (SELECT apssent_date FROM apsent WHERE day_id = 5 ORDER BY apssent_date DESC

Comment: what is best and more performance

Comment: You should show sample data and what you would want your result to look like (and specifically what it should look like based on it running on different days)

Comment: both return same data as i want , but just ask if @hagope is faster and smoother than my query .